# Youtube Player Api Mute Volume

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the youtube's code to load a video on my website but i cant find how to mute the volume. Is this possible?

```
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '300',
      width: '250',
      autoplay : 1,
      videoId: '5Wu9DxtyLWE',
      events: {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
 }
});
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
if(event.data === 0) {
}
}

</script>
```

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... Obviously i had to read more about this..
player.mute();